# Create multiple host with Vagrant and VirtualBox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I have the following problem. I need a Vagrant file to create:

- 3 Ubuntu 18.04 hosts;
- 1 Ubuntu 16.04 host.

I have the following Vagrant file:

```
require 'yaml'

# Load settings from servers.yml file.
environment = YAML.load_file('env.yaml')

...

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    environment["servers"].each do |server|
        config.vm.define server["name"] do |srv_config|
            srv_config.vm.box = server["box"]
            srv_config.ssh.insert_key = false
            srv_config.vm.hostname = server["name"]
            srv_config.vm.network :private_network, ip: server["eth1"]
            srv_config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
                v.name = server["name"]
                v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--groups", "/Development"]
                v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", server["mem"]]
                v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", server["cpu"]]
            end

            srv_config.vm.provision "file" ...
        end
    end
end
```

Now I want that this Vagrant file get the servers configuration (OS, CPU, Memory, IP, etc.) from an external `env.yml` file like this:

```
servers:
- name: node-0
  box: generic/ubuntu1804
  eth1: 192.168.20.101
  mem: 1024
  cpu: 1
- name: node-1
  box: generic/ubuntu1804
  eth1: 192.168.20.102
  mem: 1024
  cpu: 1
- name: node-2
  box: generic/ubuntu1804
  eth1: 192.168.20.103
  mem: 1024
  cpu: 1
- name: legacy
  box: generic/ubuntu1604
  eth1: 192.168.20.105
  mem: 1024
  cpu: 1
```

My problem is that I don't know why the nodes are created with:

- node-0 with Ubuntu 16.04 instead of 18.04 **<-- WHY????**
- node-1 with Ubuntu 18.04 (this is correct)
- node-2 with Ubuntu 18.04 (this is correct)
- legacy with Ubuntu 16.04 (this is correct)

As you can understand my main problem is that node-0 is created with Ubuntu 16.04 and not Ubuntu 18.04. Why? I debugged the code and for `srv_config.vm.box` for `node-0` the value is `generic/ubuntu1804`. Moreover, I correctly see 1 CPU and 1 Gb RAM for each machine, **but in Virtual Box I don't see the machines in the group Development**.
Anyone can help me to understand why these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figure out the issue. The file is correct, the problem was the Vagrant cache. I removed the `.vagrant` folder and run again `vagrant up`.